# What is this ground cover weed similar to Galenia

Tags: weeds, ground-cover

[image]
What is this ground cover weed similar to Galenia? It seems to grow in the same environment and it has a blue tone to its leaves compared to galenia. Galenia has a semi-succulent leaf, whereas this weed does not, its leaf is quite fine. Both weeds look the same from a distance as they have a similar growth pattern of a primary root that spreads out like a carpet over the ground surface and the leaves and plants are on the same scale of size to Galenia. The plants are located in the Hunter Valley, New South Wales, Australia.

Comment: Sorry to complain but the light levels are so high in your picture I can't tell what it is.  More pictures?

Comment: In addition to better pictures (e.g. details, or just high resolution, so that we can zoom), we need to know the region of the photo.  Different zones, different weeds.